# Joint probability of two correlated random variables

Tags: probability

I am interested in the following joint probability
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq a, Y\geq a)
\end{equation}
where $X, Y$ are random variables that are $\textbf{not}$ independent.

From de Morgan's formula $\mathbb{P}(A, B)=\mathbb{P}(A^c \cup B^c)$ and the inclusion-exclusion principle, one could expand the above expression as
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq a, Y\geq a)=1 - \mathbb{P}(X<a) - \mathbb{P}(Y<a) + \mathbb{P}(X\leq a, Y\leq b)
\end{equation}

However, the nature of my problem makes this rather difficult to work with. Therefore, I am inclined to do the following instead:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq a, Y\geq a) = \mathbb{P}(\min(X, Y)\geq a) = \mathbb{P}(X\geq a)\mathbb{P}(X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)
\end{align}
which is much more amenable to work with in my case. Not sure it is correct, though; my Monte Carlo simulations do not seem to overlap with this analytical result.

Is this second approach correct? Please advise.

Comment: What makes you believe that the last equality holds? It seems like you are forgetting to condition on the events $X<Y$ and $X \geq Y$.

Comment: @Galton: That was an error, I have corrected it now. Is the second approach valid now?

Comment: The second approach is not valid. As Galton mentioned, you must condition on the two events. That is, $\mathbb{P}(X \geq a)$ should be $\mathbb{P}(X \geq a \mid X < Y)$, and similarly with $\mathbb{P}(Y \geq a)$.

Comment: @Clarinetist: Yes, but it is implied I think: $\mathbb{P}(\min(X, Y)\geq a) = \mathbb{P}(\min(X, Y)\geq a \mid X<Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y)+\mathbb{P}(\min(X, Y)\geq a \mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)\mathbb{P}(X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)$

Comment: am betting the answer is no - but just in case you don't have a nice analytic formula for the copula function of your problem so you can express the joint prob in terms of the marginals?

Comment: @Clarinetist: I think Accumulation was referring to an unintentional error of mine which I afterwards corrected in my orginial post. But do you reckon it is correct now?

Comment: Not correct. There is information in the events that $X < Y$ and $X\geq Y$. The conditioning set cannot be dropped without further information on how $X$ and $Y$ interact.

Comment: Ok, there is information in the conditioned event that we cannot discard. So, with the conditioning, I would assume that at least the following is true? Otherwise, I need to get my statistics straight. $\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)\geq a)=\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)\geq a\mid X<Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y)+\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)\geq a\mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq a\mid X<Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y)+\mathbb{P}(Y\geq a\mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)$

Answer (score 1):

You actually want $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq a \mid X \lt Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a \mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)$$

and that is not the same as $\mathbb{P}(X\geq a )\mathbb{P}(X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a )\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)$, especially when both $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)$ are positive

You might intuitively think the event $X<Y$ might sometimes make the event $X \geq a$ less likely, and similarly the event $X \geq Y$ might sometimes make the event $Y \geq a$ less likely

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was wondering whether the following would be considered correct then?
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq a, Y\geq a) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)\geq a) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X\geq a\mid X<Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y) +  \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a\mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(a\leq X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(a\leq Y<X) \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{P}(a\leq X<y\mid Y=y)] + \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{P}(a\leq Y<x\mid X=x)]
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @index Your third line looks correct (apart from a $\lt$ which should be $\le$).   Your fourth looks complicated and while it may be correct, it is the kind of thing that leads to errors in calculation

Comment: Yes, I agree there is a slight abuse of the inequalities. Okay, good to know that my overall working assumption is correct. You don't think I need to include a condition in e.g. the third line that $a<Y$ and $a<X$, respectively? How else can I be certain that $a<y$ and $a<x$, respectively, in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two dice, and you want to know what the probability of them both coming up six is. There are 36 different combinations, of which 15 have the first die being less than the second, and 21 have the first equal to or greater than the second. Your formula would then take the probability of the first die being six, multiply it by the total probability of those 15 possibilities, multiply the probability of the second die being six with the total probability over the 21 possibilities, and then add those two numbers.

That doesn't make any sense. How does the probability of seeing (3,4) have anything to do with the probability of seeing (6,6)? Your formula depends on the overall probability of $X <Y$ being representative of the probability of $X <Y$ when $X\geq a$. Not only is that not guaranteed to be true, one should expect that as $X$ increases, the probability that $X$ is less than $Y$ should go down. For instance if we know that the first die is five, then we should expect that the probability that the first die is less than the second should be lower than in general. And if the first die is six, then the probability of it being less than the second die is zero.

Comment: That was an unintentional error, I have corrected it in the original post. Is the second approach valid now?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was wondering whether the following would be considered correct then?
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq a, Y\geq a) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)\geq a) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X\geq a\mid X<Y)\mathbb{P}(X<Y) +  \mathbb{P}(Y\geq a\mid X\geq Y)\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(a\leq X<Y) + \mathbb{P}(a\leq Y<X) \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{P}(a\leq X<y\mid Y=y)] + \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{P}(a\leq Y<x\mid X=x)]
\end{align*}$$