# Solving $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y)$ using truncated distribution?

Tags: probability

I am interested in the following joint probability
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y)
\end{equation}
where $X, Y$ are independent exponential random variables.

The question is on a similar theme as the problem in [Joint probability of two correlated random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831715/joint-probability-of-two-correlated-random-variables), but since the expressions of the original problems are different, I will post this as a new question.

My solution approach which I would like to double-check with you is to make use of truncated distributions:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y) 
&= \mathbb{P}(X\leq Y, X\geq a) \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \mathbb{P}(X\leq y, X\geq a) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \mathbb{P}(X\leq y \mid X\geq a) \mathbb{P}(X\geq a) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \left( \int_{z=0}^{y} f_X(z\mid X\geq a) dz \right) \mathbb{P}(X\geq a) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \left( \int_{z=0}^{y} \frac{f_X(z)}{1-F_X(y)} dz \right) \mathbb{P}(X\geq a) \right]
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from the definition of a truncated distribution.

Is the presented solution method valid?

Comment: No need to condition on $(X \geq a)$. Just write down $P\{a \leq X \leq y\}$ directly from exponential distribution.

Comment: You probably mean $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq y)=F_X(y)-F_X(a)$? This only works if $a\leq b$. We need to also take into account when $a>b$. Still, I will show why I think that won't work well in this case: $\mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq y)]=\mathbb{E}_Y[(\mathbb{P}(X\leq y)-\mathbb{P}(X\leq a))\mathbb{P}(a\leq y)+(\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)+\mathbb{P}(X\leq y))\mathbb{P}(a>y)]$, where $\mathbb{P}(a\leq y)=1_{ \left\{a\leq y\right\} }$ becomes an indicator function and therefore does not give an expression that we can analyze further. Do you agree?

Comment: $P\{a\leq X \leq y\}=0$ if $a>y$.

Comment: Really? Does not make sense to me... I am picturing the real line where for $a\leq y$ the region $[a,y]$ is shaded, whereas for $a>y$ the region $(-\infty,y]\cup [a,\infty)$ is shaded.

Comment: $\{a\leq X \leq y\}$ is the empty set if $a>y$ and empty set has probability $0$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the nice back-and-forth and for kindly answering my questions :)